# Задача о коридоре и дверях

Tags: c#, c++

Помогите перевести из C++ в C#. Я не спец в C# и не понимаю почему переведенный код работает через одно место

Группа людей должна пройти по коридору, где есть пустые комнаты и двери. Когда человек проходит впервые раз в журнал записывается `о#`, где `#` номер двери, когда другой человек во второй раз проходит двери, он ее закрывает и записывается `з#`

Рабочий код С++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <clocale>
#include <utility>

#define pb push_back
#define mp std::make_pair

std::string get_str(long long number) {
    std::string res = "";
    while (number > 0) {
        res += char(number % 10 + '0');
        number /= 10;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < res.size() / 2; ++i)
        std::swap(res[i], res[res.size() - i - 1]);
    return res;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    std::string hallway; int N;
    std::cin >> hallway >> N;
    std::vector<bool> door(N, 0); int cnt = 1;
    std::vector<std::pair<long long, int>> report;
    long long motion = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < hallway.size(); ++i) {
        if (hallway[i] == '|') {
            int amount_door = 0;
            size_t j = i;
            while (j < hallway.size() && hallway[j] == '|') {
                ++amount_door;
                ++j;
            }

            for (size_t num = 0; num < N; ++num) {
                j = 0;
                long long motion_to = motion + num * (N + 1);
                while (j < amount_door) {
                    report.pb(mp(motion_to, cnt + j));
                    ++j;
                }
            }

            i += amount_door;
            cnt += amount_door;
        }
        motion += N;
    }
    std::sort(report.begin(), report.end(), [](const std::pair<long long, int>& a, const std::pair<long long, int>& b) {
        if (a.first == b.first) return a.second < b.second;
        return a.first < b.first;
    });

    std::string ans = "";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < report.size(); ++i) {
        size_t dn = report[i].second;
        ans += (door[dn - 1] ? 'з' : 'о') + get_str(dn) + ' ';
        door[dn - 1] = (door[dn - 1] ? 0 : 1);
        std::cout << dn << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << ans << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Входные данные:

```
_|_|_|__|__|_
10
```

Выход:

```
о1 о2 з1 о3 з2 о1 з3 о2 з1 о4 о3 з2 о1 з4 з3 о2 з1 о5 о4 о3 з2 о1 з5 з4 з3 о2 з1 о5 о4 о3 з2 о1 з5 з4 з3 о2 з1 о5 о4 о3 з2 з5 з4 з3 о5 о4 з5 з4 о5 з5
```

И это правильно

---

Нерабочий код C#

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

internal static class Program
{
    public static void Resize<T>(this List<T> list, int newSize, T value = default(T))
    {
        if (list.Count > newSize)
            list.RemoveRange(newSize, list.Count - newSize);
        else if (list.Count < newSize)
        {
            for (int i = list.Count; i < newSize; i++)
            {
                list.Add(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Swap<T>(this List<T> list1, List<T> list2)
    {
        List<T> temp = new List<T>(list1);
        list1.Clear();
        list1.AddRange(list2);
        list2.Clear();
        list2.AddRange(temp);
    }

    public static List<T> InitializedList<T>(int size, T value)
    {
        List<T> temp = new List<T>();
        for (int count = 1; count <= size; count++)
        {
            temp.Add(value);
        }

        return temp;
    }

    public static List<List<T>> NestedList<T>(int outerSize, int innerSize)
    {
        List<List<T>> temp = new List<List<T>>();
        for (int count = 1; count <= outerSize; count++)
        {
            temp.Add(new List<T>(innerSize));
        }

        return temp;
    }

    public static List<List<T>> NestedList<T>(int outerSize, int innerSize, T value)
    {
        List<List<T>> temp = new List<List<T>>();
        for (int count = 1; count <= outerSize; count++)
        {
            temp.Add(InitializedList(innerSize, value));
        }

        return temp;
    }

    private static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        string hallway;
        int N;
        hallway = Console.ReadLine();
        N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        List<bool> door = InitializedList(N, false);
        int cnt = 1;
        List<Tuple<long, int>> report = new List<Tuple<long, int>>();
        long motion = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < hallway.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (hallway[i] == '|')
            {
                int amount_door = 0;
                int j = i;
                while (j < hallway.Length && hallway[j] == '|')
                {
                    ++amount_door;
                    ++j;
                }

                for (int num = 0; num < N; ++num)
                {
                    j = 0;
                    long motion_to = motion + num * (N + 1);
                    while (j < amount_door)
                    {
                        report.Add(Tuple.Create(motion_to, cnt + j));
                        ++j;
                    }
                }

                i += amount_door;
                cnt += amount_door;
            }
            motion += N;
        }
        report.Sort((Tuple<long, int> a, Tuple<long, int> b) =>
        {
            if (a.Item1 == b.Item1)
            {
                if (a.Item2 < b.Item2)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            }
            if (a.Item1 < b.Item1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        });


        string ans = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < report.Count; ++i)
        {
            int dn = report[i].Item2;
            int dan = dn;

            string res = "";
            while (dan > 0)
            {
                res += (char)(dan % 10 + '0');
                dan /= 10;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < res.Length / 2; ++j)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(res);
                char temp = sb[res.Length - j - 1];
                sb[res.Length - j - 1] = res[j];
                sb[j] = temp;
                res = sb.ToString();
            }
            ans += (door[dn - 1] ? 'з' : 'o') + res + ' ';
            door[dn - 1] = (door[dn - 1] ? 0 : 1) != 0;
        }

        Console.Write(ans);
        Console.Write('\n');
    }
}
```

Входные данные:

```
_|_|_|__|__|_
10
```

Выход:

```
o5 o3 з3 o3 o4 з4 o4 з4 o4 з4 o4 з4 o4 з4 з5 o5 з5 o5 з5 o5 з5 o5 з3 o3 з3 o3 o1 з1 o1 з1 o1 з1 o1 з1 o1 o2 з5 з2 o2 з2 o2 з2 o2 з2 o2 з3 o3 з3 з2 з1
```

И это НЕ правильно

Мне кажется у меня проблемы в C# с сортировкой

Так же был сделан код на C#, но он слишком много времени занимает 25/26 Time limit exceeded. Если возможно, то его желательно улучшить. Проблема, что входные данные безграничны, но тесты сделаны, чтоб можно было проверить код за 11 секунд. Мне сказали "идеальный код за 6 секунд справляется" и мне сказали "это задача на паттерны".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
internal static class Program
{
  private static void Main(String[] args)
  {    
    string hallway; int n;
    hallway = Console.ReadLine();
    n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    List<bool> open = new List<bool>(hallway.Length);
    for(int i = 0;i<hallway.Length;i++){
        open.Add(false);
    }
    List<int> door = new List<int>();
    for(int i = 0;i<hallway.Length;i++){
        door.Add(-1);
    }
    List<int>pos = new List<int>();
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        pos.Add(-1);
    }
        int cnt = 1;
        int lim = 1;
    int first = 0;
    string str = "";
    while(first < n){
        
         if(hallway.Length <= pos[first]){
            ++first;
            continue;
        }

        for(int i = first; i < lim; ++i){
            int cur_pos = pos[i] + 1;
            if(cur_pos > hallway.Length) continue;
            while(cur_pos < hallway.Length && (hallway[cur_pos] == '|')){
                if(door[cur_pos] == -1){
                    door[cur_pos] = cnt;
                    ++cnt;
                }
                if(open[cur_pos] == true){
                    str+="з" + door[cur_pos].ToString() + " ";
                    open[cur_pos] = false;
                }
                else{
                    str+="о" + door[cur_pos].ToString() + " ";
                    open[cur_pos] = true;
                }
                ++cur_pos;
            }
            pos[i] = cur_pos;
        }
        lim = Math.Min(n,lim+1);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(str);
  }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что означают выходные данные, вы написали, а что означают входные данные?

Comment: Входные данные это то что я ввожу в консоль, а выходные то что должно получиться, но в c++ коде я уверен в выходных данных, а при переводе в C# они должны совпасть, но увы они разные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методом дедукции и телепатии написал вот такое решение.

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string hallway = "_|_|_|__|__|_";
    int n = 10;

    hallway = hallway.Replace("|_", "|");
    int[] doorIndexes = hallway.Select((c, i) => c == '|' ? i : -1).Where(x => x >= 0).ToArray();
    bool[] doorState = new bool[doorIndexes.Length];

    List<string> log = new List<string>();
    for (int step = -n; step < hallway.Length; step++)
    {
        for (int member = n; member > 0; member--)
        {
            int position = step + member;
            if (position >= 0 && position < hallway.Length && hallway[position] == '|')
            {
                int doorIndex = Array.IndexOf(doorIndexes, position);
                doorState[doorIndex] = !doorState[doorIndex];
                log.Add((doorState[doorIndex] ? "о" : "з") + (doorIndex + 1));
            }
        }
    }
    string result = string.Join(" ", log);
    string expected = "о1 о2 з1 о3 з2 о1 з3 о2 з1 о4 о3 з2 о1 з4 з3 о2 з1 о5 о4 о3 з2 о1 з5 з4 з3 о2 з1 о5 о4 о3 з2 о1 з5 з4 з3 о2 з1 о5 о4 о3 з2 з5 з4 з3 о5 о4 з5 з4 о5 з5";
    Console.WriteLine(expected);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.WriteLine(expected == result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль.

```
о1 о2 з1 о3 з2 о1 з3 о2 з1 о4 о3 з2 о1 з4 з3 о2 з1 о5 о4 о3 з2 о1 з5 з4 з3 о2 з1 о5 о4 о3 з2 о1 з5 з4 з3 о2 з1 о5 о4 о3 з2 з5 з4 з3 о5 о4 з5 з4 о5 з5
о1 о2 з1 о3 з2 о1 з3 о2 з1 о4 о3 з2 о1 з4 з3 о2 з1 о5 о4 о3 з2 о1 з5 з4 з3 о2 з1 о5 о4 о3 з2 о1 з5 з4 з3 о2 з1 о5 о4 о3 з2 з5 з4 з3 о5 о4 з5 з4 о5 з5
True
```

C++ и C# - очень разные языки, когда дело касается обработки данных.

Comment: Извиняюсь, я скорее всего плохо формулирую мысли 
Failed test #24 of 26. Wrong answer
Что за входные данные сказать не могу, я добавил к своему основному вопросу дополнение может быть поможет разобраться в моей проблеме

Comment: @breadstickhemmo я не понял, ваш код заваливает 2 теста, или мой?

Comment: Ваш код заваливает 24 тест из 26.
А то что я добавил проходит все, но он занимает много времени и по этому не проходит.

Comment: @breadstickhemmo окей, дайте входные данные с 24 теста и ожидаемый результат. В вашем коде бросается в глаза `str+=` - конкатенация строк медленно работает, используйте например `StringBuilder`.

Comment: к сожалению, у меня нет доступа к исходным входным данным только на 1 тест были

Comment: @breadstickhemmo странные тесты. Ну тогда я не знаю, как помочь. Нечего чинить, если неизвестно, что сломалось. Если ответ был полезен, вы можете принять его. Если нет, то давайте я его удалю как бесполезный.